# how to get jstring out of jobject? c++

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface

I am trying to get a string attribute out of my jobject. I could't find any solutions to my problem, also google didn't help

**Here is my Java Class:**

```
public class HumanBean {

    String name;
    int alter;
    int gehalt;
    double gehaltDouble;

    ....getter and setter...
}
```

**CPP-File - the commented code is where I tried to get the name string out of the jobject**

```
Human createHuman(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobject javaObject) {
    jclass cls = (*env).GetObjectClass(javaObject);

    //jfieldID fidInt = (*env).GetFieldID(cls, "name", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    //jstring name = ??????????????????????

    jfieldID fidInt = (*env).GetFieldID(cls, "alter", "I");
    jint alter = (*env).GetIntField(objarg, fidInt);

    jfieldID fidInt = (*env).GetFieldID(cls, "gehalt", "I");
    jint gehaltInt = (*env).GetIntField(objarg, fidInt);

    jfieldID fidInt = (*env).GetFieldID(cls, "gehaltDouble", "D");
    jdouble gehaltDouble = (*env).GetDoubleField(objarg, fidInt);

    Human newHuman = Human(alter, name, gehaltDouble, gehaltInt);

    return newHuman;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but note that `(*foo).method(...)` is better written as `foo->method(...)`

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work:

```
jfieldID fidName = (*env).GetFieldID(cls, "name", "Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring nameString = (jstring)(*env).GetObjectField(cls, fidName);
```

Comment: The key point here is that `jstring` inherits from `jobject`. This downcast is safe (you are retrieving a `String`, after all), but the compiler cannot know that.